# Using SSE to speed up lower_bound function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, sse

In a project I'm currently working on I often need to find the lowest possible index in a sorted array at which an element can be inserted (like std::lower_bound in C++).
It seems pretty attractive to me to use SSE to speed up my algorithm since I'm working with uint32 arrays which size is typically the size of a processor cache line.
I've never used SSE instructions before, so I can't manage to figure out what an SSE implementation of this function would looks like. Please give hints to help me write it out optimally wtih SSE.

Comment: Take time to do some research. Then think about it and perhaps try a few things to get a "feel" of how it works. Then ask a more directed question -- there is no question here.

Comment: I found the pcmpled which compare 4 32bits packed integers with a 32bit operand, but I cannot managed to find how to get the result of this instruction. Maybe you could point out a good reference on how to use this instruction (or the corresponding intrinsic) if you have one?

Comment: Seems like I was wrong; pcmpled compare two vector4 of 32bit integers and fill a vec4 with 0 and 1 depending on the result of the comparison. Nothing exploitable for me. Seems like Billy ONeal is right, SSE will be no use for me.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing like `std::lower_bound` is going to scale well using SSE. The reason SSE makes things faster is that it allows you to do several calculations at once. For example, a single SSE instruction might result in 4 multiply operations going on at once. However, the way `std::lower_bound` operates cannot be parallelized, because each step in the algorithm requires the comparison results of previous steps. Plus, it's already O(lg n), and as a result unlikely to be a bottleneck.

Moreover, before moving to inline assembly, you should know that whenever you use inline assembly, you defeat most compiler optimizations that might occur on that section of your program, and often as a result your program will be slower -- compilers usually write better assembler than us humans do.

If you want to use SSE, you are better off using *intrinsics* -- special "functions" or keywords provided by the compiler, which call the SSE instruction but otherwise allow optimizations to occur. Such intrinsics are available in [Microsoft's Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx), as well as the [GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html#X86-Built_002din-Functions). (And probably most any compiler. Consult your compiler's documentation)

Rather than trying to speed up `std::lower_bound` using SSE, you should try to not need to call it in the first place. For example, if you're constantly inserting elements into the vector using `lower_bound`, you should know what you've effectively created is [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), and a poor insertion sort at that, which will require quadradic time. You would likely be better off simply putting your new elements on the end of the vector, and then sorting the vector when you need it sorted, which reduces things to an O(n lg n) sort. If your data access patterns are such that you would be resorting too often then you should use something like a `std::set` instead, which provides O(lg n) operations for insertions, rather than the O(n + lg n) insertions you're currently getting with the vectors.

And of course, remember to benchmark :)